# Python micro web service always hang

Tags: python, web-services, io, wsgi, bottle

I built a micro web service but I find it hangs a lot. By hang I mean all requests will just time out, when it hangs, I can see the process is running fine in server using only about 15MB memory as usual. I think it's a very interesting problem to post, the code is super simple, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
app = Bottle()
# static routing
@app.route('/')
def server_static_home():
    return static_file('index.html', root='client/')

@app.route('/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='client/')

@app.get('/api/data')
def getData():
    data = {}
    arrayToReturn = []
    with open("data.txt", "r") as dataFile:
        entryArray = json.load(dataFile)
        for entry in entryArray:
            if not entry['deleted']:
                arrayToReturn.append(entry)
        data["array"] = arrayToReturn

    return data

@app.put('/api/data')
def changeEntry():

    jsonObj = request.json
    with open("data.txt", "r+") as dataFile:
        entryArray = json.load(dataFile)
        for entry in entryArray:
            if entry['id'] == jsonObj['id']:
                entry['val'] = jsonObj['val']
        dataFile.seek(0)
        json.dump(entryArray, dataFile, indent=4)
        dataFile.truncate()

    return {"success":True}

run_simple('0.0.0.0', 80, app, use_reloader=True)
```

Basically `mydomain.com` is route to my `index.html` and load necessary JS, CSS files, that's what static routing part is doing. Once page is loaded, an ajax `GET` request is fired to `/api/data` to load data and when I modify data, it fires another ajax `Put` request to `/api/data` to modify data.

**How to reproduce**

It's very easy to reproduce the hang, I just need to visit `mydomain.com` and refresh the page for 10-30 times rapidly, then it will stop responding. But I was never able to reproduce this locally how ever fast I refresh and `data.txt` is the same on my local machine.

**Update**

Turns out it's not problem with read/write to file but a problem with trying to write to broken pipe. The client that sent request close the connection before receiving all the data. I'm looking into solution now...

Comment: If you're using the development server included with the Bottle framework, I've noticed that broken pipe errors are practically inevitable, given sufficient uptime (it is a dev server after all). If that applies to you, I'd recommend switching to running your Bottle application on top of a more production-ready server. I've personally had really good results from using Bottle with cherrypy.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to open and read the same `data.txt` file with every `PUT` request. Eventually you are going to run into concurrency issues with this architecture as you will have multiple requests trying to open and write to the same file.

The best solution is to persist the data to a database (something like MySQL, Postgres, Mongodb) instead of writing to a flat file on disk.

However, if you must write to a flat file, then you should write to a different file per request where the name of the file could be the `jsonObj['id']`, This way you avoid the problem of multiple requests trying to read/write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Because the service is really simple I don't want to use any database for it. I'm reading and modifying entries in a json format text file, so I don't think I can write to separate files, then reading data will be very complex.

Comment: Moreover, I think the problem is with the `GET` requests not `PUT` because I don't need to modify data to reproduce the problem, refreshing will only fire the `GET` request that reads data.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing to your data.txt file will be victim as race conditions as Calvin mentions.  Databases are pretty easy in python especially with libraries like SqlAlchemy.  But if you insist, you can also use a global dictionary and a lock assuming your webserver is not running as multiple processes.  Something like

```
entryArray = {}
mylock = threading.Lock()
@app.put('/api/data')
def changeEntry():

    jsonObj = request.json
    with mylock.lock:
        for entry in entryArray:
           if entry['id'] == jsonObj['id']:
              entry['val'] = jsonObj['val']
```

Comment: I don't think it's race conditions now, it seems to be single-threaded by default - http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/serving/